# How to "use" folder as a class file?

Tags: laravel, opencart

In opencart, there are files in helper folder

```
/system/  
    helper/  
        utf8.php
        general.php
```

**system\helper\utf8.php**

```
<?php
namespace Opencart\System\Helper\Utf8;
mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');

function strlen(string $string) {
    return mb_strlen($string);
}

....
```

**system\startup.php**

```
require_once(DIR_SYSTEM . 'helper/general.php');
require_once(DIR_SYSTEM . 'helper/utf8.php');
```

**backend\controller\catalog\product.php**
In product controller

```
<?php
namespace Opencart\Admin\Controller\Catalog;
use \Opencart\System\Helper as Helper;
class Product extends \Opencart\System\Engine\Controller {

    public function save(): void {
        ...

        foreach ($this->request->post['product_description'] as $language_id => $value) {
            if ((Helper\Utf8\strlen(trim($value['name'])) < 1) || (Helper\Utf8\strlen($value['name']) > 255)) {
                $json['error']['name_' . $language_id] = $this->language->get('error_name');
            }
            ...
        }
```

**Question:**
system/helper is a folder, not a class. How can it be used as a class?

```
use \Opencart\System\Helper as Helper;
```

When we use a class method, I only know dash and arrow: $Object->func(). How to use slash?

```
Helper\Utf8\strlen()
```

Utf8 is also not a class, just a file with functions

I tried to do things like this in Laravel, but get

```
Call to undefined function App\Http\Controllers\ProductController\Helpers\Utf8\strlen()
```

The path is not right. It's app\Helpers\utf8.php

UserController

```
use App\Helpers as Helper;
...
        require_once(app_path('Helpers/utf8.php'));
        echo Helpers\Utf8\strlen('adsf');
```

How to use Helper\Utf8\strlen() ?

Comment: i guess you need to learn php`PSR 4` Autoload https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/

Comment: you can use laravel inbult helper function if your using laravel (as per tag) https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/helpers#method-str-length